# Splitting ASCII grid files into WGS84 GTiff chunks with sliding bbox defined in degrees minutes seconds

Tags: gdal, tiles, wgs84

## Context

I have (many! i.e. >> 500) [ASCII Grid](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm) raster files given in [`EPSG:2154`](https://epsg.io/2154), which headers look like (as an example):

```
ncols        1000
nrows        1000
xllcorner    939999.5000
yllcorner    6495000.5000
cellsize     1.000000000000
NODATA_value  -99999.00
```

On the other hand I have two separate WGS84 points defining the top-right and bottom-left corner of a rectangle. Both points are given with an even 2 [minutes of arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_and_second_of_arc) precision, e.g. 47°20' N and 4°32' E.

## Goal to achieve

I need to build new chunks inside the rectangle defined by the two WGS84 points using a tile size of 2 minute of arc each, in both directions (N-S and W-E).

The data are on a remote Ubuntu 18.04 server on which I can connect through SSH. There is not graphical user interface.

I was thinking using [gdal_retile.py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_retile.html) but tile size must be given in pixels, which, for me, relates to a Cartesian coordinate system, not a spherical (ellipsoidal) one.

## Question

How could I build such tiles in WGS84 in an elegant way?

What I've done so far (which may be a useless step) is converting all *.asc files into a single (but large!) geotiff and re-projected it to [`EPSG:4326`](https://epsg.io/4326):

```
#!/bin/bash
gdalbuildvrt output.vrt -overwrite *.asc
gdal_translate -of GTiff output.vrt output.tiff
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:2154 -t_srs EPSG:4326 output.tiff output_4326.tiff
...
```

From here, I was also thinking of looping (in bash) between both the N-S and W-E min and max values using the `-te` option of [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html), i.e. building my own sliding windows with a 2 minutes of arc size. Unless I missed something, I will have to convert the minutes of arc to decimal degrees... which would be a little tedious (or is it possible to give WGS84 bbox coordinates as degrees, minutes, seconds? From the doc, I cannot figure it out), but if I don't have a more elegant choice, I'll stick to it.